# How to manual create a format which includes LaTeX and a package e.g. calculator for a bare eTeX?

Tags: tex-core, e-tex

I'm able to make fmt-files with the packages `mylatex` or `mylatexformat` in my Tex Live 2019 installation but I need a file `mycalclator.tex` for a use case as follows

```
einitex *mycalculator.tex \dump
```

that does all the work.

I need a source-file which combines the LaTex format and a preamble with selected LaTeX packages e.g. calculator but also others and several combined for a bare eTeX engine.

<strike>Any existing options from the packages should be setable from the application file that will be compiled with the generated format.</strike>

**Update 31.07.2019**

- only concerns usage of Jim Fowler's Pascal to WebAssembly compiler [web2js](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js)

Since I still have problems with the memory management of eTeX / LaTeX I'm going to test the answer with `plain.tex` and `eplain.tex`.

Dumping eplain per `eplain.ini`

```
% Thomas Esser, 1998. public domain.
% hyphenation is set up in language.dat

\input bplain
\input eplain
\dump
\endinput
```

This would correspond to scenario 2 ( fmt file is not available) but without RequirePackage

Comment: Could you give an example application about what you mean by that mixing of LaTeX and TeX packages? I don't think changing package options after the package has already been loaded by the format file is possible in general, unless a specific package explicitly defers the options processing e.g. via `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: @siracusa I don't think the question mentions any mixing of LaTeX and TeX packages? It also doesn't seem to be asking anything about changing package options. As I understand it, the question is the following: what can I type into a file `mycalculator.tex`, such that the effect of running `einitex *mycalculator.tex \dump` (rather than running `mylatex` or `mylatexformat`) is to create a format file equivalent to `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{calculator} \usepackage{tikz}` (or something like that).

Comment: @siracusa  ShreevatsaR has put it in a nutshell. I only have an eTeX engine and I need both actions of first loading the LaTex format and second loading a preamble for LaTeX packages defined in this file `mycalculator.tex` so I can get a special fmt file for my use case.

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi I still don't understand your note about the package options. Do you want to set them in `mycalculator.tex` or from the actual file that uses the new format?

Comment: @siracusa In the actual file that uses the new format. But it doesn't matter for now. I crossed it out in my question. What is important is the basic structure of 'mycalculator.tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MiKTeX the following sequence gives the desired result, as far as I understand your question (the command-line syntax for TeX Live seems to be a bit different, but I don't have a TeX Live system here to test):

**Scenario 1: The `latex.fmt` format file is already available**

- Create a file `mycalculator.tex` with the following content:

  ```
  \RequirePackage{calculator}
  ```
- Run

  ```
  etex -initialize "&latex" mycalculator.tex \dump
  ```

  to create the `mycalculator` format, based on the `latex` format.

**Scenario 2: The `latex.fmt` format file is NOT available**

- Create a file `mycalculator.tex` with the following content:

  ```
  \let\origdump=\dump
  \let\dump=\relax
  \input latex.ltx
  \let\dump=\origdump
  \RequirePackage{calculator}
  ```
- Run

  ```
  etex -initialize mycalculator.tex \dump
  ```

  to load the LaTeX definitions and create the `mycalculator` format.

In both cases a user file `calctest.tex` like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\pi \approx \numberPI$
\end{document}
```

compiled via

```
etex "&mycalculator" calctest.tex
```

should result in a .dvi file with the contents

> π ≈ 3.14159

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi Yes, `&latex` loads an already existing `latex.fmt`. In theory you should be able to get the same result by using `\input latex.ltx \RequirePackage{calculator}` in the format specification. However, that seems to ignore the loading or the `calculator` package here, and I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi Found the problem, please see the update

Comment: Nice answer, +1! With TeX Live (2019), the first scenario can be done with `etex -ini '&latex' mycalculator.tex '\dump'` (single quote-based quoting depends on the shell, of course, but should be appropriate in most cases). For the second scenario, this is trickier: one apparently has to enable e-TeX's extended mode, otherwise it starts in compatibility mode and `latex.ltx` won't be loaded fine. This can be done like this: `etex -ini '*' mycalculator.tex '\dump'`. Note that the `'*'` is not  required (and wouldn't work!) in the first scenario, because...

Comment: ...  “Whenever a format file is loaded by `eINITEX` or `eVIRTEX` the mode (compatibility or extended) is inherited from the format” (quote from the e-TeX manual, § 2.2).

Comment: @siracusa @frougon Can I include a format file in a format specification?  I've seen something like `%&latex`, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi I don't understand the vocabulary you are using. If you start a LaTeX document with `%&latex
\documentclass{article} (...)`, you can compile it with `pdftex` or `pdfetex`, as opposed to `pdflatex`. `%&latex` tells the TeX engine to load `latex.fmt`.

Comment: @frougon You say LaTeX document and I say format specification when I want to use the LaTeX document to **dump a fmt file**. I understand from your answer that I can also use %&latex in a format specification to dump a fmt file.